# Safe to share local git repository between OS'

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

I have two OS' installed on my computer with a common separate drive used for storing my local git repository. Is it safe to access the same physical local repo from both OS' (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12)?

I downloaded the most recent versions of git, but the version numbers are different on each OS. Windows has 1.7.11 and Ubuntu has 1.7.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe

The git internal storage format is well-defined and the OS file system layer would need to be trying very hard to subvert it for it to fail when accessed from different operating systems.

Comment: Thanks! And it is ok that the git version numbers differ?

Comment: Yes-- in general.  Some advanced features (sub-modules) have changed a little since first introduced but developers have strived for safe backward compatibility and any issues are featured prominently in the documentation.  I think you'd have to be mixing a very old version (1.5 or less) with a recent one to run into any difficulties at all.